# Embeddings of $L^p$ spaces over the range $0 < p < \infty$

Tags: functional-analysis, lp-spaces

Suppose that $\Omega$ is an open subset of $\mathbb R^n$.

Let $p \in (0,\infty)$. We say that $f : \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb R$ is in the space $L^p(\Omega)$ if it satisfies
$$\int_\Omega |f|^p dx < \infty.$$

These spaces are quasi-Banach spaces, Banach spaces for $p \geq 1$, and there are known bounded inclusions when $p \geq 1$ and the set $\Omega$ has finite measure:
$$
L^q(\Omega) \subseteq L^p(\Omega) \text{ if } q > p.
$$
**Question:** What inclusions are known over the entire range $p > 0$ (under what conditions on $\Omega)$?

I suspect that $L^1(\Omega) \subseteq L^p(\Omega)$ **as an inclusion of sets** whenever $\Omega$ is bounded and $p < 1$, but is that embedding a bounded inclusion?

Comment: $L^1(\Omega) \subseteq L^p(\Omega)$ whenever $\Omega$ is bounded and $p < 1$ and the embedding  is bounded by Holder. Try to show some attempt on your part.

Comment: Dear Op,  F-spaces do you know about it? The question was interesting for motivation just Try on discrete sum,  although i think for a sequence which is bounded considering the $\sum a_n^p$ is a great motivation to proceed.